# Why a Zend Framework module create a session in APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session" and not in the "session.save_path" of php.ini?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, zend-form

On windows (not checked on other environments), the quickstart tutorial FORM code

```
$this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', array(
'ignore' => true,
));
```

creates a session file in the directory set up in the "session.save_path" variable of php.ini (something like "c:\wamp\tmp")

But if you put the same same code in a module, it tries to create the session file in the directory APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session" which doesn't exist by default so an exception is raised.

If the solution is to create this "date/session" directory, it doesn't explain why a module doesn't use the one in the "session.save_path" variable of php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the provided [`Zend_application_Resource_Session`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.session) to set up your `save_path`:

```
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
```

You can still set it to `/tmp` if you want.

Comment: I agree and I'll do it but it doesn't explain why this code in a module doesn't use the "session.save_path" variable of php.ini.
Thanks anyway.